# Cannot figure out output of SQL query

Tags: sql

There are 2 tables:

[image]

And a query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT A FROM R1 AS a
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT * FROM R2 AS b
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT * FROM R1 AS c
        WHERE c.A = a.A AND c.C = a.C AND c.B = b.B
    )
);
```

The answer is `1, 3` but I cannot figure out why. Can someone explain to me why the answer is this?

Comment: Run the query and see if it returns anything.

Comment: Yes, it does. The answer is not empty.

Comment: it's not clear what your question is

Comment: My answer is wrong, I wanna know the correct answer and where my logics are wrong.

Comment: What do you wish to get as result ? 1,2,3,4,5 ?

Comment: I know the answer: `1, 3`. I want to know why.

Comment: The inner query is **not** comparing equal elements. a and c reference the same table but represent different rows. The query will run for each row of a and compare it with each row of c.

Comment: The question seems clear enough to me.

Comment: @DcCoO the question has it's edit history...

Answer (score 1):

I do not understand the question 100% but I will do my best:

I believe this is the part that confuses you:

```
WHERE c.A = a.A AND c.C = a.C AND c.B = b.B
```

If you change it to

```
WHERE c.A = a.A AND c.C = a.C AND c.B = a.B
```

You will get the result you are talking about and you are expecting to get.

[Here is the demo.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=9fbfe2f37dd56bbb07ba84496bc87e2f)

Ok if it is not clear to you why, then maybe this will help:

**1**

```
insert into R1 values(1, 'b', 'w')
insert into R1 values(1, 'a', 'w')
insert into R1 values(1, 'c', 'w')
```

**3**

```
insert into R1 values(3, 'a', 'p')
insert into R1 values(3, 'c', 'p')
insert into R1 values(3, 'b', 'p')
```

This above are the data responsable for the result of `1,3`.
They are the ones that have `c.A = a.A AND c.C = a.C AND c.B = b.B`

Comment: I'm not expecting my result to be right, I'm wondering why it is wrong. I don't want to change the original query to fit my result, I want to understand it.

Comment: By the way, you mispelled the line `insert into R1 values(1, 'b', '1')`, it should be `insert into R1 values(1, 'b', 'w')`.

Comment: I noticed, repaired it right after your comment "I know the answer: 1, 3. I want to know why. "

Comment: Hi @Daniel, I have updated my answer... Maybe it will help. Cheers.

Comment: Hi @Daniel, if you have any more problems understanding please do ask...

Comment: I'm sorry but your answer is not clear, those values you mentioned doesn't mean anything for my understanding of the question right now. I think I'm having a little problem with the `NOT EXIST` thing. I'm studying about it.